# Umbraco - Render .Net User Control (ascx) macro with Razor

Tags: razor, macros, render, umbraco

I have a razor script in Umbraco that is quite complex and I want at some point of it to render a macro in it.

The macro which is called SuggestionBox is actually a user control (.ascx) and traditionally this is referenced on the template using

```
<umbraco:macro Alias="SuggestionBox" language="cshtml" runat="server"></umbraco:macro>
```

But now I need to call it from the razor script instead so I tried;

```
@Html.Raw(umbraco.library.RenderMacroContent("SuggestionBox", Model.Id))
```

as well as:

```
@RenderPage("SuggestionBox")
```

No luck so far as I'm sure I'm using these wrongly.

I read somewhere it might be infeasible if the page is wrapped in a masterpage.

It works if I add it to the Template like I traditionally would:

```
 <umbraco:macro Alias="EventsRenderer" language="cshtml" runat="server"></umbraco:macro>
 <div class="talkingPointPanel">
    <h3><umbraco:Item field="talkingPoinstSuggestionText" runat="server"></umbraco:Item></h3>
    <umbraco:macro Alias="SuggestionBox" language="cshtml" runat="server"></umbraco:macro>
 </div>
```

Where EventsRenderer renders the page that should ideally contain the SuggestionBox.

using

```
@Html.Raw(umbraco.library.RenderMacroContent("<?UMBRACO_MACRO macroAlias=\"SuggestionBox\" />", Model.Id))
```

Gives me this error:

```
<!-- Error generating macroContent: 'System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): HtmlForm cannot render without a reference to the Page instance.  Make sure your form has been added to the control tree.

   at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.Render(HtmlTextWriter output)

   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)

   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)

   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)

   at umbraco.presentation.templateControls.Macro.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)

   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)

   at umbraco.library.RenderMacroContent(String Text, Int32 PageId)' -->
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I didn't try this with .Net control inside Razor (only razor inside razor) and worked wonders. @RenderPage("~/macroscripts/dotMailerMessageBox.cshtml") Even if it doesn't work for you, it might be useful for someone else..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
<umbraco:Macro runat="server" language="cshtml">@{

HtmlTextWriter writer = new HtmlTextWriter(this.Output);
var navigation = new umbraco.presentation.templateControls.Macro();

navigation.Alias = "Navigation";
navigation.MacroAttributes.Add("ulclass", "art-vmenu");
navigation.MacroAttributes.Add("level", 2);

navigation.RenderControl(writer);   }</umbraco:Macro>
```

Try something like this. It works for me ... I have made a Navigation macro. Be Aware though your variables should be given in toLower, if caps are used, the parameters will not come through.

Comment: Thank you! That comment about "ToLower" ended several hours of head-desking

Comment: Please make it clear the concept of "toLower". im stuck with this.

Answer (score 2):

In Umbraco 4.10+ To call a macro inside Razor script, use:

@Umbraco.RenderMacro("macroNameHere", new { propertyName1 = CurrentPage.pageProperty }))

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
@Html.Raw(umbraco.library.RenderMacroContent("<?UMBRACO_MACRO macroAlias=\"SuggestionBox\" />", Model.Id))
```

Comment: I get this error :


 <!-- Error generating macroContent: 'System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): HtmlForm cannot render without a reference to the Page instance.  Make sure your form has been added to the control tree.

Comment: Hmm... I'm thinking the error is coming from the user control. Do you have any problems adding the user control macro to your page in the standard way (outside of your razor macro)? Also there may be a conflict if your master page and your user control both contain form tags. ASP.Net doesn't like nested form tags.

Comment: The control works fine if I add it on the template the traditional way, but because the razor script contains a lot of markup, I want it to appear in a specific place within the page.
However, as a temporary solution I have the control appearing at the bottom of the page after the contents of the razor script have been rendered and that works.

Comment: So it works to add it in the razor script, but only outside of the present markup? Can you post some markup?

Comment: No it doesn't work in the razor script no matter where I put it. The error is the one I've posted on my first comment.

It only works if I use it from the template. Check the updated question to see markup.

Comment: Hmm... that doesn't give me much to go on. Is it possible to post the source of the user control?

Comment: the control contains a form with one textbox and a button and it sends an email with the content of the textbox. It's super simple and as I said it works well if I add it outside the razor script, but it appears at the end of the page instead of in the middle of it.

The razor script just loops through some elements and prints a table with rows. There's nothing weird about it..