# Render ascx user control from razor macro in Umbraco 4.7

Tags: .net, razor, macros, umbraco, ascx

I've had this problem [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10689284/umbraco-render-net-user-control-ascx-macro-with-razor) and never got it to work but this time I have no alternative way of going around it and really need to get this working.

I have a simple ascx control that reads an RSS feed and outputs it in simple html. The code behind is pretty simple.

Then I have a razor script that renders an entire page and within a certain area of that page I want to add my ascx control.

If I add the control straight on the template like this:

```
<umbraco:macro Alias="SubnavRenderer" language="cshtml" runat="server"></umbraco:macro>
```

it works well but the blog entries appear outside the content.

So from inside the razor script I do something like this:

```
foreach (var item in Model.Children) 
    {
        ...
        else if(item.NodeTypeAlias == "Blog")
             {
               @Html.Raw(umbraco.library.RenderMacroContent("<?UMBRACO_MACRO macroAlias=\"BlogRenderer\"></?UMBRACO_MACRO>", Model.Id));
             } 
        }
```

This renders an empty div but the content fail to render in it so the macro is half-working.
I am suspecting it is connected to the lifecycle of the page. The macro has a page_load event that probably is skipped or something like that.

Any ideas?
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

When I first read your post I was going to suggest that you added an asp:PlaceHolder where you wanted the macro and then use the [Page PreInit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx#lifecycle_events) event to dynamically generate the control and pop it into the placeholder.

I was also going to suggest you use [uQuery](http://ucomponents.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=uQuery) (which comes with ucomponents and is in the Umbraco core from 4.8 - so that your razor script simplifies to something like:

Model.GetNodesByType("Blog");

But looking at your html.raw command, perhaps thats the problem - shouldn't you be using **item.Id** instead of **Model.Id**?

**EDIT**

You could try [escaping your macro declaration - that's worked for me before](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/umbracolibrary/rendermacrocontent); also you could add runat="server" attribute.

Comment: Using item.Id made no difference whatsoever. Also changing the version from 4.7 to 4.8 is also not possible, the project is on a remote server.
I did try to add a page load into the macro script but nothing was achieved by that. I'm hitting a wall with this one.

Comment: @Nick If you add the ucomponents package to your 4.7 build you will have access to uQuery.

Comment: I've sent a request to the server manager to install it. Assuming they do, what would I have to do then in the razor script?